# Scaling ImageView crops the image (added dynamically to windowmanager)

Tags: android, imageview, crop

i created a floating button, not connected to any activity or viewgroup
 (added it directly to the window manager), which i want to grow and shrink on touch.
However, scaling it more than 1 crops the image that i want to display.
How can i grow the imageview to match the rescaled image inside?

this is some relevant code:

Creating the AnimatedButton, which extends ImageView in the service class OnCreate
(AnimatedButton extends ImageView and just adds some extra drawing on top of the image when OnDraw is created,
don't think its code is relevant here):

public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mFloatingButton = new AnimatedButton(this);
    mFloatingButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ax);

    ...
    ...

    params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    //this code is for dragging the chat head
    mFloatingButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        ...

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ...
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (isAClick(initialTouchX, event.getRawX(), initialTouchY, event.getRawY())) {
                        ...
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFloatingButton, "Scale", 1.0f, 3.0f);
                        anim.setDuration(700);
                        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                        anim.setRepeatCount(1);
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    });

    windowManager.addView(mFloatingButton, params);
    ...
```

}

and this is setScale of AnimatedButton:

public void setScale(float scale)
{

```
  mScale = scale;
  this.setScaleX(mScale);
  this.setScaleY(mScale);
  invalidate();
```

}

tnx

Comment: Can you post some code of how you are scaling it currently?

Comment: put some code samples.

Comment: posted some code, tnx!